# How to run Javascript unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have some *.js which is suppose to be the unit tests. I am not sure how to invoke them.

```
describe('test123', function() {
        blah blah blah;
});
```

Comment: Which Unit Testing framework are you using?

Comment: I am not sure. This is a legacy code, so ask here.

Comment: Various Unit Testing frameworks are used in various different ways. Some run in the browser, others require a Node server, and yet others have other dependencies. Without knowing more, we cannot tell you how to invoke yours.

Comment: For us to identify the framework, you'll need to show some of the test cases within the `describe()` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be Jasmine. If that is the case, you can learn more about it at http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/, and you can invoke them with the SpecRunner. You can see a simple project example online here: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/A-simple-project.